# no such column error code doesn't work when using 4.4 Kitkat

Tags: android, sqlite, android-4.4-kitkat

I created an application on min android 5. But I want to run it at 4.4 android. So I copied files from first project to second and corrected things like AndroidManifest. When I'am compiling first version evrythink works ok, but on version who should works with android 4.4 I get SQLite exeption "no such column". 
Code:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select, container, false);
        helper = new MobilnaPytajkaDatabase(getContext());
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query("QUIZ_TABLE", new String[]{"_id", "QUESTION"},
                "TYPE=0", null, null, null, null, null);
        lista = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            try {
                CursorAdapter ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(),
                        R.layout.whitetextlayout1, cursor,
                        new String[]{"QUESTION"}, new int[]{R.id.text1},
                        0);
                lista.setAdapter(ca);
                lista.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                ;
            }
            return view;
        }
        else
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.emptylist, container,false);
    }
```

SQLite open helper class:

```
package com.nieruchalski.mobilnapytajkaforkitkat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MobilnaPytajkaDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public final static int DB_VERSION = 2;
    public final static String DB_NAME = "QUIZ_DATA";

    MobilnaPytajkaDatabase(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE QUIZ_TABLE (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + "QUESTION TEXT"
        + "ANSWER TEXT"
        + "TYPE INTEGER);");
    }
}
```

Logcat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.nieruchalski.mobilnapytajkaforkitkat, PID: 2450
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nieruchalski.mobilnapytajkaforkitkat/com.nieruchalski.mobilnapytajkaforkitkat.selectQuiz}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: TYPE (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, QUESTION FROM QUIZ_TABLE WHERE TYPE=0
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: TYPE (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, QUESTION FROM QUIZ_TABLE WHERE TYPE=0
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:921)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:532)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:68)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1402)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1249)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1120)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1326)
                      at com.nieruchalski.mobilnapytajkaforkitkat.selectFragment.onCreateView(selectFragment.java:38)
                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2238)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:977)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1152)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1539)
                      at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6278)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with Kitkat really. You're just missing commas `,` between columns specifications in `MobilnaPytajkaDatabase#onCreate()`. Add them there and uninstall your app to remove the old database and create a new one.